# Store JSON to localstorage not working

Tags: javascript, angular

After pushing a button I would like to save an item (nested JSON) into a new Array and store it to the localstorage.

```
addFavourite(card) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(card));
    var cards = [];
    this.cardfavouriteArray.push.apply(cards, card)
    this.storage.set('favouriteData', this.cardfavouriteArray);
    }


getData() {
    var data = this.storage.get('favouriteData');
    if(data){
      this.storage.get('favouriteData').then((val) => {
        console.log('test', JSON.stringify(val));
      });
    }
```

I get no error, but 'test' is always empty. I need it as an array.

Comment: What is the storage service you are using? Is it custom built or a third party? All the provided answers will solve the problem but that logic really should be abstracted away within the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Set`** and **`Get`** method for `localstorage` varies on which service you are using

1.**HTML5 localStorage**- If you are using HTML5 localStorage directly then you should use `localStorage.getItem`
and `localStorage.setItem`

2.localstorage is limited to store only string key/value pairs.Use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse when using setting and getting from localstorage

```
addFavourite(card) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(card));
    var cards = [];
    this.cardfavouriteArray.push.apply(cards, card)
    this.storage.setItem('favouriteData', JSON.stringify(this.cardfavouriteArray));
    }


getData() {
    var data = this.storage.get('favouriteData');
    if(data){
      this.storage.getItem('favouriteData').then((val) => {
        console.log('test', JSON.parse(val));
      });
    }
```

3.**ng2-webstorage**- In case of **`ng2-webstorage`** **`this.storage.retrieve`** and **`this.storage.store`** will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.storage.set('favouriteData', this.cardfavouriteArray);` to `localStorage.set('favouriteData', JSON.stringify(this.cardfavouriteArray));` (It's a pre-defined method by angular). Also stringify the array.

Answer (score 0):

Set array in local storage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('favouriteData', JSON.stringify(this.cardfavouriteArray));
```

Get array from local storage like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favouriteData'));
```

Explanation: It is because localstorage can not store object, it stores in string format. So we need to JSON.stringify the object. Also localStorage has function name setItem and getItem as defined here: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage. When we get the string from localstorage, we need to JSON.parse to convert it back to object.

You are using this.storage.set and this.storage.get. It is not clear which library are you using, but the code I mentioned will work in Angular or any framework. Since localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem is pure javascript.

Comment: @NullPointer, It is because localstorage can not store object, it stores in string format. So we need to JSON.stringify the object. Also localStorage has function name setItem and getItem as defined here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage. When we get the string from localstorage, we need to JSON.parse to convert it back to object.

Comment: add in your answer

Comment: and what about getItem and setItem correction...Where is its explanation.Add this also

Comment: @NullPointer, Done.